# Fancybox - getting html from element based on id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have the following snippet;

```
$("a.lightbox_image").each(function () {
        $(this).fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'speedIn': 600,
            'speedOut': 200,
            'content': $('#lightbox_image_content_'+this.id.replace('lightbox_image_','')).html()
        });
    });
```

But the above does not get the content from the element referenced to in the content property - what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell. I would recommend starting debugging the result of the `replace()` operation and checking whether the element actually exists.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Open a fancy-box with different content that corresponds to the clicked link?

Comment: Zuul: Excatly. The default content (if i remove the content property) is an image with a title - basic stuff. But i want i slightly different layout of the lightbox (a link above the picture, 2 text paragraphs below the picture etc). 

Pekka: The element excist (have checkeded and double checked) and the replace method works.

Comment: Just tried this: "'content': '#lightbox_image_content_'+this.id.replace('lightbox_image_','')" - this displays the correct id of the element i am trying to get the html of - so the problem lies somewhere in the way i reference to the jquery function or something like that. (and the id it showed excist in on the page)

Answer (score 1):

the replace function needs a regular expression so try `replace(/lightbox_image_/, '')`
and try to get the `val()` in stead the `html()`

```
$("a.lightbox_image").each(function () {
  var id = "lightbox_image_content_"+this.id.replace(/lightbox_image_/,'');
  var content = $("#"+id).html();
        $(this).fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'speedIn': 600,
            'speedOut': 200,
            'content': content;
        });
    });
```

Comment: The replace function works fine (have tested it), but just to double check, i tried your code above, and the result is the same as mine - it did not work i'm afraid :-(

Comment: did you also tryed with val() instead with html()

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. It turns out it is not allowed to have `{}` in the `this.id`. After removing these from the id, it worked.